# How to get a pixel movement when using "optical flow"

Tags: image-processing, 2d, pixel, opticalflow

I'm doing 2D-Image processing and I have a quick question:

does optical flow provide the movement detection for a given Pixel, or is it just working with this information (i.e. you need an additional method to get this data)?

For what I've seen I'm assuming, that you need to provide the movement in x and y on your own, but on the other hand it is working with a constant pixel intensity (from one image to the next), which I guess should be obsolete if you already got the movement information

Has anyone a hint? Since all the tutorials, literatures, lectures I've seen skip this important step

Answer (score 1):

Optical flow calculates this movement for you.  You need to specify the pixels coordinates in the first frame, and some parameters as to the target search region, and then it calculates the movement.  The problem is that it's not always correct, and in some cases, not possible, when the pixel is not really distinguishable from its surroundings.

In OpenCV, the function goodFeaturesToTrack usually precedes optical flow, as it detects pixels that have higher likelihood of being processed correctly.  Even then, you still need to do some extra processing to verify that the movement was correct.

Comment: But how is this calculated ? *delta x*, *delta y* isn't very informative. I need to implement this without using a predefined function (such from openCV)

Comment: The origin x,y is up to you.  If you need a specific position use it.  If not, use some detector.  If you want to know how the optical flow calculates the movement, it is documented in various papers and in the OpenCV open source code.

Comment: please can you provide me such a paper where this is explained, as mentioned above I always get explications where they skip this step.

Comment: You can start here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas–Kanade_method    There are links to papers there.

Comment: Well but here's the same: they are talking about *partial derivatives of the image I* without explaining directly what it's about - I don't no what a derivative of an image is, the only method I could think of would be a discrete laplacian (but which order ?)

Comment: That's how scientific papers work.  They assume you have a working knowledge of the subject matter.  If you don't and still want to understand the matter, go and study from the basics.

Comment: I understand everything else but the *derivation of an image* that's what this question is about

Comment: Did you try:   image derivative    in google?    It produces the following nice result:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient